# How to fill a grid make its total be largest

Tags: list-manipulation, algorithm, puzzle

I have a blank grid whose dimension is 5*5.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I want to fill it with some number using 1, 2, 3 and 4. But in every blank space if you fill 2, its neighbor (include four direction, such as left, right, top and bottom) must have a 1 at least. If you fill 3, its neighbor must have a 2 and a 1 at least. If you fill 4, its neighbor must have a 3, a 2 and a 1 at least. I think the total maybe is near to 50.

```
Mean@Table[
  Total[RandomChoice[{.4, .3, .2, .1} -> {1., 2, 3, 4}, {5, 5}], 2], 
  1000000]
```

> 50.0017

But I really don't know how to fill the blank grid to make its total of **all number** to be largest?

---

There is sample filled grid from @Quantum_Oli's answer but its the total isn't largest

[image: img]

As the @Bill 's [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/111725/how-to-fill-a-grid-make-its-total-be-largest#comment303274_111725),I made a boolean expression name as `GoodQ`,It is ulgly,But anyway,It works

```
neighborNum[mat_, num_, nei_] := 
 And @@ ((And @@ (Function[tem, MemberQ[#, tem]] /@ 
         nei)) & /@ (Extract[
        mat, #] & /@ (Select[#, 
          And @@ Thread[
             1 <= # <= 5] &] & /@ ((Table[{#, #2}, 
              4] + (Join[#, -#] &[IdentityMatrix[2]])) & @@@ 
          Position[mat, num]))))
GoodQ[list_] := 
 And @@ MapThread[
   neighborNum[list, #, #2] &, {{2, 3, 4}, {{1}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}}}]
```

We can check the matrix in the @Quantum_Oli's [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/111730/21532) and in the @garej's [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/111725/how-to-fill-a-grid-make-its-total-be-largest#comment303295_111730)

```
m = {{3, 2, 1, 2, 3}, {1, 4, 2, 4, 1}, {2, 3, 1, 3, 2}, {1, 4, 2, 4, 
    1}, {3, 2, 1, 2, 3}};
m2 = {{1, 4, 2, 4, 1}, {2, 3, 1, 3, 2}, {1, 4, 2, 4, 1}, {2, 3, 1, 3, 
    2}, {1, 4, 2, 4, 1}};
m3 = {{2, 1, 2, 1, 2}, {4, 3, 4, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 1, 2, 1}, {4, 3, 4, 3, 
    4}, {2, 1, 2, 1, 2}};
GoodQ /@ {m, m2, m3}
```

> {True, True, True}

Comment: Why the downvote?could you give a reason?

Comment: Although I am not the down voter, I do find the question quite unclear. For instance, how do you calculate the total? Row totals? Column totals? Perhaps you could show an example of a completed square for clarity. Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: @MarcoB Sorry,Actually I don't know how to start this question.If I have some progress,I must will show in the post.

Comment: An essential part of the solution will be a boolean expression which is True if the matrix satisfies your conditions and False otherwise. Can you write out such an expression?

Comment: @Bill I made a boolean expression,but a little ulgly.

Comment: @yode, why maybe 57 is not maximum? It is not. I've shown you that at least `59` is possible (`m3` matrix and its siblings).

Comment: @garej Thank point out that.As I know some layout can up to 61,but I have not that grid.

Comment: @yode, I see. So did you tried brute force?

Comment: @garej But 4^25 is a too large number

Comment: @yode, can we diminish the number of combinations with all possible combinations that has 25 members and sum up to 61?

Comment: @garej Maybe that method cann't expand to 6*6 or more large grids.

Comment: @yode, but at least it would show the pattern, whether it is symmetric or sparse.

Comment: @garej Good suggestion,I'll give a try after a moment.:)

Comment: It seems that this question can be answered with brute force combinatorial optimization. Are the matrix sizes only 5x5 or other (larger) sizes a considered?

Comment: @AntonAntonov Yes,we should considered the larger matrix.And the brute force fail in my this computer.Or you can post a anwer use brute force.

Comment: @yode By "brute force combinatorial optimization" I did not mean brute force enumeration-and-testing of possible layouts. I will post an answer in the next few days...

Comment: @AntonAntonov Look forward to that.:)

Comment: @yode Could you explain how the rules work in the case of incomplete neighborhoods, e.g. corners? For instance, if I put a 4 in the top left corner of your 5x5 grid, that cell only has bottom and right cells, so it necessarily can't have 1, 2, and 3 around it. What should it then have to be valid? Anything? 3 and 2? Or does that actually mean that **one can't put a 4 in a corner at all**?

Comment: @MarcoB Yup.As the rule we could not put a 4 in the corners.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Below is given a solution derived with ILP combinatorial optimization:
The total of the assigned values to the $5 \times 5$ table is $61$.

I called in the comments this approach to be "brute force" because of the generation of a larger number of variables and conditions and pushing them to `Maximize` or `LinearProgramming`. Same approach was used for [my answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/99827/34008) in the discussion ["Refining subset relations"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/99274/refining-subset-relations).

### Integer programming formulation

#### Set-up parameters

Dimensions of the $m \times n$ table:

```
{m, n} = {5, 5};
```

We consider placing the integers $[1,\dots,d_{max}]$, $d_{max} = 4$ in the $m \times n$ table.

```
dmax = 4;
```

#### Variables

Let us make the binary variables $x(k,i,j)=x_{k,i,j}$, $k \in [1,\dots,d_{max}]$, $i \in [1,\dots,m]$, $j \in [1,\dots,n]$ in the following way: $x(k,i,j) = 1$ if the integer $k$ is placed at position $(i,j)$ and it is 0 otherwise.

```
ClearAll[vars, x]
vars = Flatten[Array[x, {dmax, m, n}]];
```

#### Neighbor conditions

Let us define a function (as described in the question) that brings a set of index pairs for the neighbors of given cell $(i,j)$:

$ninds(i,j):= \{ 0 < p_1 \leq m, 0 < p_2 \leq n : p \in \{ (i-1,j),(i+1,j),(i,j-1),(i,j+1)\} \}$ .

```
NeighborIndexes[{i_, j_}] := {{i - 1, j}, {i + 1, j}, {i, j - 1}, {i, j + 1}};
NeighborIndexes[{i_?NumberQ, j_?NumberQ}, {m_, n_}] := 
  Select[{{i - 1, j}, {i + 1, j}, {i, j - 1}, {i, j + 1}}, 
   0 < #[[1]] <= m && 0 < #[[2]] <= n &];
```

For each cell $(i,j)$ and an integer $k > 1$ placed on that cell we have the conditions:

$\sum_{p \in ninds(i,j)} x(d,p_1,p_2) \geq 1, d \in [1,\dots,k-1]$.

For example, for the integer 4 and $(i,j)$ such that $ninds(i,j)$ has all four neigbors we have :

[image]

Note that by the nature of the definition of the variables $x(k,i,j)$ we can re-write the neighbor conditions as:

$\sum_{p \in ninds(i,j)} x(d,p_1,p_2) \geq x(k,i,j), d \in [1,\dots,k-1]$.

(This is a very convenient way to keep the maximization problem linear.)

#### Neighbor conditions generation

Let us generate the conditions. This can be done in several ways.

```
CellConditions[k_, {i_, j_}, {m_, n_}] := 
  Table[Total[Map[x @@ Prepend[#, d] &, NeighborIndexes[{i, j}, {m, n}]]] - x[k, i, j] >= 0, {d, 1, k - 1}];
```

Example of this function:

```
CellConditions[4, {3, 3}, {m, n}]

(* {
 x[1, 2, 3] + x[1, 3, 2] + x[1, 3, 4] + x[1, 4, 3] - x[4, 3, 3] >= 0, 
 x[2, 2, 3] + x[2, 3, 2] + x[2, 3, 4] + x[2, 4, 3] - x[4, 3, 3] >= 0, 
 x[3, 2, 3] + x[3, 3, 2] + x[3, 3, 4] + x[3, 4, 3] - x[4, 3, 3] >= 0}
*)
```

Generating all neighbor conditions:

```
neighborConds = 
  Flatten@Table[
    CellConditions[d, {i, j}, {m, n}], {d, 2, dmax}, {i, 1, m}, {j, 1,
      n}];
neighborConds // Length

(* 150 *)
```

#### Other constraints

In order to finish the formulation two other types of constraints have to be added.

**1.** Uniqueness constraints. (Only one integer is assigned per cell.)

```
uniqueConstraints = 
  Map[Total[Cases[vars, x[_, #[[1]], #[[2]]]]] == 1 &, 
   Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, 1, m}, {j, 1, n}], 1]];
uniqueConstraints // Length

(* 25 *)
```

**2.** Positivity / bounded-ness constraints:

```
varConstraints = Map[0 <= # <= 1 &, vars];
```

Because of the uniqueness constraints we do not need to specify $\leq 1$, but I have put it there as a reminder.

#### Solution with Maximize (too slow)

At this point we can find the solution with `Maximize`:

```
sol = Maximize[
  Join[{vars.vars[[All, 1]]}, neighborConds, uniqueConstraints, 
   varConstraints], vars, Integers]
```

Using `Maximize` though is **too slow**. I was able to get solutions only for smaller tables and number of integer values to be assigned, e.g. a $3 \times 4$ table and $d_{max} = 3$.

To get the solutions faster we can formulate the problem through vectors and matrices and use `LinearProgramming`.

### Integer Linear Programming formulation

#### Convert from symbolic to matrix formulation

```
{zeroMat, neighborCondsMat} = 
  CoefficientArrays[neighborConds[[All, 1]], vars];
Dimensions[neighborCondsMat]

(* {150, 100} *)

{zeroMat, uniquenessCondsMat} = 
  CoefficientArrays[uniqueConstraints[[All, 1]], vars];
Dimensions[uniquenessCondsMat]

(* {25, 100} *)

bVec =
  Join[
   Table[{0, 1}, {Dimensions[neighborCondsMat][[1]]}], 
   Table[{1, 0}, {Dimensions[uniquenessCondsMat][[1]]}]
   ];

condMat = 
 Join[Normal[neighborCondsMat], Normal[uniquenessCondsMat]];
MatrixQ[condMat]

(* True *)
```

#### Solution with `LinearProgramming`

Using `Table[{0, 1}, {Length[vars]}]` as a fourth argument is not necessary because of the uniquness conditions.

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 lpSol = LinearProgramming[-vars[[All, 1]], condMat, bVec, 0, Integers]
]

(* Out[74]= {44.4484, {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
  0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  1, 0, 0}} *)

lpSol = Thread[vars -> lpSol];

vars[[All, 1]].lpSol[[All, 2]]

(* 61 *)
```

#### Visualize the solution

```
pSol = Select[lpSol, #[[2]] == 1 &];
solMat = SparseArray[Map[Rest[#] -> First[#] &, List @@@ pSol[[All,1]]]];
MatrixPlotWithValues[solMat]
```

[image]

(The definition of the function `MatrixPlotWithValues` is given below.)

### Other solutions

#### $5 \times 6$ table

I tried the code above for a $5 \times 6$ table and got the following result after 422 seconds (10 times longer than for $5 \times 5$) on the same computer:

[image]

The total is $74$.

#### $6 \times 6$ table

Because of a comment by @garej I computed the layout for a $6 \times 6$ table (7182 seconds on the same computer):

[image]

The total is $90$.

### Solution visualization function

Here is the function used for the plots above:

```
MatrixPlotWithValues[mat_?MatrixQ] :=
  Block[{gr, m, n},
   {m, n} = Dimensions[mat];
   gr = MatrixPlot[mat];
   Graphics[{gr[[1]], 
     MapThread[
      Text, {Flatten[Transpose@Reverse@mat], 
       Flatten[Table[{i, j} - 1/2, {i, n}, {j, m}], 1]}]}, 
    Frame -> True, 
    FrameTicks -> {Table[{i - 1/2, i}, {i, n}], 
      Table[{j - 1/2, m - j + 1}, {j, m}]}]
   ];
```

### Generalizations

The solution can be easily adapted for possible generalizations of the problem formulation with tables that are one of:

1. 3D cube,
2. surface of a 3D cube,
3. cylinder,
4. torus,
5. Mobius strip.

Comment: Very cool (+1). Can you say whether this is guaranteed to be the global maximum or not?

Comment: @Rahul Thanks! I am not sure what LinearProgramming does for when the domain is Integers. If Branch-and-bound is used with relaxation to standard linear programming then finding the minimum is guaranteed. (Similarly for Maximize.)

Comment: @yode, so it is sparse :))) Interesting also that it has six 4's and six (!) 3's. When in comes to 6 X 6 what should be the range `1..4` or `1..5`?

Comment: @garej For the integers set `1..5` we still have $\leq 4$ defined neighbors, but only free to use permutations of `1..4` for them. I was thinking that for `1..5`, `1..6`, and `1..7` we have to go to 3D.

Answer (score 8):

**EDIT: Verification function:**

```
    ValidMatrixQ[m_] := 
     With[{labelling = Flatten@m}, 
      AllTrue[Range[25], 
       ContainsAll[labelling[[AdjacencyList[GridGraph[{5, 5}], #]]], 
         Range[labelling[[#]] - 1]] &]
    ]
```

Is this a valid example? **EDIT, Take 3: Grid courtesy of garej**

```
m = {
  {3, 2, 1, 2, 3},
  {1, 4, 2, 4, 1},
  {2, 3, 1, 3, 2},
  {1, 4, 2, 4, 1},
  {3, 2, 1, 2 , 3}
 }
```

[image]

In which case perhaps adding it to your question will help clarify what you are after. Also the total is 57...

No guarantees this is maximised!

Comment: it should be something like `m = {{3, 2, 1, 2, 3}, {1, 4, 2, 4, 1}, {2, 3, 1, 3, 2}, {1, 4, 2, 4, 1}, {3, 2, 1, 2 , 3}}`

Comment: Ha, yes! Harder than it looks! Thanks.

Comment: @yode, to get `59` try `{{2, 1, 2, 1, 2}, {4, 3, 4, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 1, 2, 1}, {4, 3, 4, 3, 4}, {2, 1, 2, 1, 2}}`...

Comment: @garej Thanks a lot.

Comment: Beautifully `ValidMatrixQ`